# What does the -lcs50 command line argument do in clang?

Tags: c, arguments, clang, cs50

Is it a combination of the -l -c and -s arguments? That is my best guess, but why would that be the case if -s only runs the preprocess and compiler when -c does all that and assembles? And what is the 50 on the end for?

Answer (score 4):

`-l_libname_` is a switch to tell the compiler (the linker) to include the library named `_libname_` in the link phase.

`-lcs50` tells the linker to include the [`cs50` library](https://manual.cs50.net/library/).

Comment: For example, the `-lcs50` might find `libcs50.so` or `libcs50.a`.